# Jquery form validation, focusout event working only for first time

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I want to validate a form instantly using jquery. Actually the validation occurs after focus out. But the validation occurs only for the first focus out and not for the next focus out events.
Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sivadass/osmmbpcb/10/) link.
I want to achive validation for every focusout events, please help... TIA

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#emailid').focusout(function() {
    var emailCheck = $(this).val();
    if ($.trim(emailCheck).length == 0) {
        $(".validation-error").toggleClass("visible").delay(3000).fadeOut(900);
    }
    if (validateEmail(emailCheck)) {
        $(".validation-success").toggleClass("visible").delay(3000).fadeOut(900);
    }
    else {
        $(".validation-error").toggleClass("visible").delay(3000).fadeOut(900);
    }
});
});

function validateEmail(emailCheck) {
var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
if (filter.test(emailCheck)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this part should be rewritten as below.
Otherwise if you make an error and correct it later your error message won't always disappear.

```
if ($.trim(emailCheck).length == 0) {
    $(".validation-error").addClass("visible").delay(3000).fadeOut(900);
} else {
    $(".validation-error").removeClass("visible");
}

if (validateEmail(emailCheck)) {
    $(".validation-success").addClass("visible").delay(3000).fadeOut(900);
    $(".validation-error").removeClass("visible");
}
else {
    $(".validation-error").addClass("visible").delay(3000).fadeOut(900);
    $(".validation-success").removeClass("visible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read up on what toggleClass does [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

after you fadeOut check the style of the validation-error element